Requesting Feedback on My First PCB Design: Improvements, Grave Mistakes, and Next Steps
I'm a beginner in PCB design and recently created my first design. Since I am a skydiver I thought a simple device for detecting altitude would be a nice point to start and fun to test. I would greatly appreciate your feedback on it!
My goal is to understand whether the design is usable for initial testing and learn how to improve it for future iterations. Specifically, I’m looking for feedback on the following points:

Any grave mistakes that might render the PCB unusable or cause
unexpected behaviour.
Suggestions on areas to improve or common best practices I may have
overlooked.
Recommendations on topics to study in more depth to enhance my
skills for future designs.

You can find the KiCad files here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EAoDnsrgBrahHZizqUs5aYhkQ_MrF2pc/view?usp=sharing




Please post images in your post. Otherwise the question will be useless to anybody else when the link dies. Welcome to EE.SE.

Thanks! I added some pictures, let me know if you need more


Yes. Please read MCU documentation and use the MCU  accordingly, especially how to provide power supplies and how to make USB properly. 2&3) are somewhat off-topic due to asking for opinion-based things. Sorry, but open-ended review questions are difficult.


C9 seems to be shorted in the schematic. In general, you could add way more info on the schematic. E.g. the SDO to GND seems to be a short in first place, but the datasheet of the humidity sensor tells us that this is the I2C address selector. Your PCB layout could be improved: Use a full GND plane and connect all supply caps as short as possible to that plane.

@StefanWyss Thanks for pointing that out! I removed the short on c9 and i will add some more info to the schematic.

@Justme Thanks for pointing that out, I looked it up and realized I used the wrong manual after downloading a bunch of them, when deciding on what MCU to use. Could you elaborate on the USB part please? It was just meant to provide power for charging the battery and not a lot of transmitting so i thought setting it up like this would work.

@DaBlackFish For USB, why is R13 in the schematics? You need to have eveything correct or USB does not transfer any data, and then the MCU cannot know how much current you can pull for charging the battery. You need to ask the source if it's OK to pull 100mA, 500mA, and you can't even negotiate more, unless the MCU supports BC negotiation. Is the USB data pair drawn as a differential pair with 90 ohm impedance? My guess is no, because it looks like two layer PCB, and it's typically not possible on a standard 2 layer board.

There’s plenty of random kinks in the tracks - did you use an autorouter?? Don’t use an autorouter. The layout around U5 is probably not what the manufacturer intended. It all looks randomly placed - try to align components.it makes the pcb neater and more professional looking. For slightly extra cost, go four layer for a decent groundplane and easier routing.
